# bash script hangs wihout obvious reason

Tags: shell, sh

I've got this bash script that builds a Docker image and kicks off a set of tests on it:

```
#!/bin/bash

fails=''

inspect() {
  if [ $1 -ne 0 ]; then
    fails="${fails} $2"
  fi
}

docker-compose up -d --build
docker-compose exec -T users python manage.py test
inspect $? users
docker-compose exec -T users flake8 project
inspect $? users-lint
docker-compose exec -T client npm test -- --coverage
inspect $? client
docker-compose down

docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml up -d --build
docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml exec -T users python manage.py recreate_db
./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --config baseUrl=http://localhost
inspect $? e2e
docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml down

if [ -n "${fails}"]; then
  echo "Test failed: ${fails}"
  exit 1
else
  echo "Tests passed !"
  exit 0
fi
```

but it won't exit out when finished. It just hangs. What can I do to troubleshoot this ?

Comment: run your script with `bash -x <scriptname>` and inspect the last command it is getting hung at.

Comment: I'm getting what I'm supposed to get which is result of all tests. But the script should exit out on its own but won't.

Comment: You're missing a space before `]` in the final  if clause.  My guess is that `docker-compose` is not finishing.

Comment: @WilliamPursell  Adding space didn't help.

Comment: @mr_incredible How are you running it? Is it from a regular terminal with `bash -x scriptname` or from some kind of CI or testing framework? If it's from a terminal, does anything happen if you press enter while it hangs?

Comment: @thatotherguy   When I hit Enter at the end of it it just keeps going down endlessly until I press CTRL+C. I get the same behaviour when running on GitLab CI runner. Yes, I'm running it locally from my Ubuntu laptop where I'm using the Cypress e2e testing library but I'm running it headlessly on CI. Enzyme is Js testing library for React-based apps. And using Python's unittests. All of which exit out on its own successfully when ran independently. But when ran from the bash script as a whole it hangs.